# MySQL - Delete a row, how?

Tags: php, mysql, rows

Can anyone show me a query in MySQL that would delete rows from all available columns.

I use this to insert rows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . KEYS . "          // KEYS is a constant
 (key, user_id, time, approved)
 VALUES ('" .  $randkey . "', '" . $user_id . "', '" .  $time . "', '0')";
```

I need the opposite of this now, delete created rows.

Comment: I don't quite get, why it's down-voted. Yes, it noobish and not great worded... and so what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using similar syntax sql = "DELETE FROM " . KEYS . " WHERE 1=1";

Replace 1=1 with the conditions for the row you want to delete or it will delete all rows.

Also, it's good to get out of the habit of just dropping variables into SQL as soon as possible, because it will open your code up to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  Look into using parameterized queries.

Comment: Can you show me those please? I want to drop everything from that table, but the code provided doesn't delete everything. Why?

Comment: 1=1 is always true. That should delete everything.

Comment: TRUNCATE tablename will delete all rows and reset any autoincrement counters associated with the table;  DROP tablename will get rid of the table; ALTER TABLE tablename DROP COLUMN columname will permanently remove a column from a table.  Not sure which of those you're going for here.

Answer (score 3):

```
delete from <table> where ....
```

Keep in mind that the delete statement is always for an entire row.

Comment: it's always a good idea to put a limit as well if you know how many rows you intend to delete.  Usually you are only looking to delete 1 row, so a LIMIT 1 can save you if you ever have a mistake in your WHERE clause or God forbid, you forget to put one!

Comment: @ajacian81  I disagree, this way you'll just hide bug.

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov the bug will still be there, if he meant to delete a specific row but the query would actually delete more than 1 row, it's quite likely that the deleted row would not be the one he was meant to delete and it would be observable.  Better than deleting hundreds/thousands of rows irrevocably.

Comment: @ajacian81: consider this scenario: user hits "delete" - nothing happens (in his eyes), he hits it few more times - works!

Comment: @ajacian81: I think such bugs must be caught by minimal testing during development. And in those rare cases (in my 4 years of db dev I've never seen or heard of such bug in production) when it happens, you must have backups (or even better - smth like Oracle's flashback queries). If devs/db admins don't do both... I'd hardly call them professionals. The problem with the approach - it indulges sloppiness/uncertainty - "Oh, instead of checking `WHERE` I'll just put `LIMIT`". Come on, it's not that hard - simply make sure you've covered all PK/unique key columns - only a couple of conditions.